# Which status use when iterate into the same request?

Tags: rest, api-design, http-status-codes

I have a concern about which status code need to use in the following scenario:

Suppose that I have the following endpoint:

```
https://my-restaurant.api.com/v1/orders
```

And I made a `POST` request with some elements inside of the body to start a new order:

```
{
  date: "2018-08-10T09:00:00.000-03:00",
  order: 12345
}
```

The response would be the following:

```
{
  require_additional_data: true,
  customers: [],
  waiter: "Jon Doe"
}
```

Here, the service tells that need more data before to close the order. The next step would repeat the request with the same body, but with more data about the order.

The response status code should be a `200 OK` in this case? I guess that would be `200 OK` once that the service tells that order was finished and have all the information required.

Until that, which status code would be used?

Comment: 422 unprocessable entity, see e.g. https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

Comment: _jonrsharpe_'s comment is quite accurate and provides such a great resource for picking a status code response. I've added some details to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51896389/1426227) explaining why `200` is unsuitable here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) for this situation. Keep in mind that [`2xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) status codes indicate that the request was successfully received, understood, and accepted by the server. That's not your case.

A [`4xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) status code would be more suitable for the situation described in your question. You could use [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) as pointed in the comments. It indicates that the request entitity cannot be processed due to semantic errors (but it's sintatically correct). See the definition below:

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Comment: I think that my problem was badly explained, but the server request was received successfully on the first iteration. I guess that the status code needs to be 206 Partial Content

Comment: @JonathanBrizio `206` is not meant for that. In your question, you state that _The next step would repeat the request with the same body, but with more data about the order_. I only can think about a client error status code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the state cycle or constraints of your order ressource :

- Can an order resource (in your database or any persistence layer) be empty?

  - If yes, you should return 200.
  - If no, you should return a 400 Bad request. You can also return a 422 who will be more precise.

Both are good answers.
If creating an order is for you a long process, which need multiple requests, then an order could be empty.

e.g. :

1. Create empty order
2. Add first meal
3. Add second meal
4. Add wine

If creating an order is one atomic request, or you don't want to see any empty order in your base the order cannot be empty.